# rabbitMQ queue mirroring policy is not working

Tags: rabbitmq, set, queue, policy, mirroring

I have set up a cluster with 3 nodes and have queue already declared. then I set up a new policy with queue mirroring. I can see the policy under web UI but the queue still not showing up as mirrored. Does anyone know what to check?

Comment: I am seeing 'NaN' from the webUI for those queue, but list_queue show them all "running" as state.

Answer (score 1):

Since the list_queue show them all "running", it appears that the queue is running properly, however it appears that the management plugin is having issue in collecting the status and showing it.  You can try resetting the management database and wait until management data is collected again. Try [restarting stats DB](https://www.rabbitmq.com/management.html#stats-db) and also disabling, re-enabling the management plugin.

In case if the above does not resolve the problem, perform a full cluster restart and if that also does not work out, check whether you are operating with older version of rabbitmq and try migrating towards latest rabbitmq which would have a better management plugin.